# How to pivot and sum data from a joined table

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, pivot, aggregate-functions

I have two tables A and B as below.
Table A

| slip | component | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ss-001 | PF | 1500 |
| ss-001 | PT | 200 |
| ss-002 | PF | 1450 |
| ss-002 | PT | 150 |
| ss-003 | PF | 1550 |
| ss-003 | PT | 300 |

**Table B**

| emp | slip | netpay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| emp-001 | ss-001 | 18500 |
| emp-002 | ss-002 | 17000 |
| emp-003 | ss-003 | 16600 |

how may I get below Table through query?

| emp | PF + PT | netpay |
| --- | --- | --- |
| emp-001 | 1700 | 18500 |
| emp-002 | 1600 | 17000 |
| emp-003 | 1850 | 16600 |

I am able to get PF and PT in two different columns but unable to SUM.

I tried `SUM()` and `CONCAT()`.

Comment: show us the query you have tried. also, which column you wanted to sum? have you tried to `select slip, sum(amount) from tableA where component in ('pt', 'pf') group by slip`?

Comment: PF and PT are values inside column "component" in Table  A

Comment: On the topic of queries which "pivot and sum": [MySQL Pivot Query with Sum of column value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37801133/2943403) and [MySQL get sum of a table columns - PIVOT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67606999/2943403) and [Getting sum of multiple columns and calculate each row's ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14720657/2943403) and [mysql pivot query results with GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6605604/2943403) and [MYSQL: Group By and SUM different columns with different criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72424155/2943403)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the conditional aggregation as follows :

```
select emp, sum(case when component = 'PF' then amount end) 
            + sum(case when component = 'PT' then amount end) as 'PF + PT', 
            max(netpay) as netpay
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.slip = b.slip
group by emp;
```

Results :

```
emp     PF + PT netpay
emp-001 1700    18500
emp-002 1600    17000
emp-003 1850    16600
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zijzBMYd)

Answer (score 1):

A simple correlated query should be enough:

```
select emp, (
    select sum(amount)
    from table_a
    where table_a.slip = table_b.slip
) as "PF + PT", netpay
from table_b
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm under-appreciating your minimal example, but my observation is that the `b` table is "one" and the `a` table is the "many".  I'd probably fetch `FROM b` and then only `JOIN a` on `slip` and only the rows with the component values that you are going to sum.  This way you don't need to explicitly perform comparisons inside of the `SUM()` function for every row returned -- because there's no "fat" to possibly trim.

SQL: ([DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/K15GDfuw))

```
SELECT b.emp,
       SUM(a.amount) `PF + PT`, 
       b.netpay
FROM tableB b
JOIN tableA a ON b.slip = a.slip AND a.component IN ('PF', 'PT')
GROUP BY b.emp, b.netpay
```

I'm no SQL expert, but I assume this would be more ideal than running a subquery foreach row in the SELECT clause.  I also cannot say with confidence if it is faster to GROUP BY two columns to avoid `MAX()` in the select, or just GROUP BY one column and call `MAX()`.